# How to test a non-integer number with if in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

i try to validate if a number with decimals is between in a specify range, i mean like the following example :

```
rangeA=58.5
rangeB=61.5
number=62.7

 if [[ ( "$number" > "$rangeA" | bc ) || ( "$number" = "$rangeA" | bc ) ]] && [[ ( "$number" < "$rangeB" | bc ) || ( "number" = "rangeB" | bc ) ]]; then
```

but i'm stuck in this operation, I would appreciate your help
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash's `<` and `>` compare strings, `-lt` and `-gt` compare integers, the only way to compare floating point numbers is to shell out to `bc(1)` (which you do, but you do it wrong):

```
rangeA=58.5
rangeB=61.5
number=62.7

if (( $(bc <<<"$number >= $rangeA && $number <= $rangeB") )); then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

`bc` prints 1 or 0 to the standard output, and bash's arithmetics context (`((expression))`) tests it for zero and sets the status code accordingly.

Comment: thanks, both answer are great, the only doubt here is how to hide the standard output of bc ?

Comment: @shaveax There's no bc output in my answer.

Comment: sorry about that, my bad , thanks :)

Comment: Don't encourage use of backticks.  `$()` is a better choice for readability (and sometimes even correctness).  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082.  Also, bash implements `<<<` by writing the data to a file in `/tmp` and redirecting from that.  `echo ...|bc` would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @PeterCordes Re backticks. Yeah, I know `$()` is better, didn't think it matters in this case. Fixed it. Re `<<<`. I think it still communicates the intent better and the fact that bash implements it that way now can be improved in the future. Using `echo` is prone to its own set of problems.

Comment: I misread the code initially, I thought you had `$rangeA` as the beginning of the string to be `echo`ed, in which case you know it doesn't start with a `-e` or something.  Also, if you like parentheses, try an arithmetic context for boolean evaluation:  `if (( $(bc <<< "...") )); then `.  It's pretty clean for boolean variables, e.g. `if (( var ));then`, with a few caveats.

Comment: @PeterCordes ((expression)) is clearly the most elegant way. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use awk:

```
rangeA=58.5
rangeB=61.5
number=62.7

if awk -v number=$number -v rangeA=$rangeA -v rangeB=$rangeB  '
   BEGIN{exit !(number >= rangeA && number <= rangeB)}'
then
   echo "condition matched"
else
   echo "condition didn't match"
fi
```

Comment: the second `||` should be a `&&`

Comment: Your example prints "condition matched" when the number is clearly out of range (even if the second `||` is replaced with `&&`). And there's also the output from `bc` (0s and 1s) left hanging. The general problem is that `bc` doesn't set the exit status depending on its result.

Comment: Ah my bad, check updated answer now.

Answer (score 1):

`bc` can do complex tests on numbers using "and", `&&`, or "or", `||`, logic.  If the condition is true, `bc` echoes `1` to stdout.  We can test for `1` using `grep -q 1` where the `-q` option tells `grep` to be quiet and produce nothing on stdout:

```
if bc <<< "$number >= $rangeA && $number <= $rangeB" | grep -q 1
then
    echo True
else
    echo False
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your `if` is a requirement, but you could also use the ternary operator in `awk`:

```
awk -v n=$number -v a=$rangeA -v b=$rangeB \
    'BEGIN{print(n >= a && n <= b)?"yes":"no"}'
```

Sort of an implied if-else.